# Querying cassandra error no viable alternative at input 'ALLOW'

Tags: json, scala, cassandra, cql, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to run a query on Cassandra through spark.

When running this command:

```
val test = sc.cassandraTable[Person](keyspace,table)
               .where("name=?","Jane").collect
```

I get the appropriate output for the query.

When I try to use the `where` statement to enter the query as a whole string I get an error.

I receive the query as a json:

```
{"clause": " name = 'Jane' "}
```

then turn it into a string.

When running

```
val query = (json \ "clause").get.as[String]
//turns json value into a string
val test = sc.cassandraTable[Person](keyspace,table)
                   .where(query).collect
```

I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT "uuid", "person", "age" FROM "test"."users" WHERE token("uuid") > ? AND token("uuid") <= ? AND  name = Jane    ALLOW FILTERING: line 1:232 no viable alternative at input 'ALLOW' (...<= ? AND  name = [Jane]    ALLOW...)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:288)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:302)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$18.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:328)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$18.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.foreach(CountingIterator.scala:4)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
```

I suspect that when I turn the json value " name = 'Jane' " into a string, I lose the single quotes hence I get " name = Jane " which of course raises an error. I tried escaping the single quotes with \ and with a second pair of single quotes around the name Jane `{"clause": " name = ''Jane'' "}`. It doesn't solve the issue.

Edit: After further testing it's definitely the json that loses the single quotes and CQL needs them to perform the query. Can anyone suggest a way to escape/save the presence of the single quotes? I tried escaping with `\` double single quotes `''` . Is there a way to use JSON to provide proper whole CQL statements?

Comment: You've identified the issue, if you can get those quotes through you'll be fine. I'm pretty sure they are being removed by the `.get.as[String]` so I would double check that. I'm pretty sure that `.where` won't modify your string.

Comment: I was actually suspecting the part ` WHERE token("uuid") > ? AND token("uuid") <= ? AND`  since it appears after the where clause and I did not include that in the string I parsed. But yeah, after switching to text to test if json was the issue, turned out that was it. Thanks!

Comment: Np, the "Token" portion is for doing the distribution of work in Spark. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Unicode character `\u0027`.